# Can we make the view3D background transparent

Tags: actionscript-3

Can we make the view3D background transparent so that i can see the video that i want to play behind the view3D
I want to place the 3D model above the video

Answer (score 0):

In that case you'll need to use the [StageVideo](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html) class, as it sits behind the `Stage3D` layer.